# how to remove old project .war file and add new .war file in jboss

Tags: jboss

i have a maven java project called `event`. now i shifted to another project called `date`. in Jboss i have already deployed `event.war` file and i want to remove and add this `date.war`. i have tried to deploy `date.war` file by using JBoss Management but it shows an error.  in J boss folder what i have to do. am i want to delete some folder in jboss deployment folder.is it possible to do that or am i want to install another jboss. please explain me

Answer (score 1):

hi you can delete the date.war file or folder int he deployments directory. then you should be able to deploy your new date.war using JBoss Management CLI or just copying it to the deployments folder.